# Configure ESB Toolkit 2.2 on Windows 10 issue, 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, esb-toolkit-2.0, esb-toolkit-2.1

Trying to install ESB toolkit 2.2 (BizTalk 2013 R2) on Windows 10, BizTalk installed and configured, IIS also configured, but got the error 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Cannot figure out why, help please.

Comment: Windows 10 isn't currently supported by BizTalk.  At any rate, check the event logs, see if you can find out what file it can't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the system diagnostics in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk ESB Toolkit\Bin\ESBConfigurationTool.exe.config

[Enable system diagnostics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcR1D.png)

if you can able to see below error. This is what causing it.

```
Stack Trace:
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UnsafeNativeMethods.IADs.Get(String bstrName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.BindSam(String target, String userName, String password)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.Validate(String userName, String password, ContextOptions connectionMethod)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(String userName, String password, ContextOptions options)
   at EsbConfigurationTool.Panels.PanelBase.ValidateCredential(NetworkCredential credentials, String groupName)
   at EsbConfigurationTool.Panels.WebServicesException.Save()
   at EsbConfigurationTool.EsbConfiguration.OnTsBtnSaveClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This method "ValidateCredentials" is trying to get registry entries in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
which are not available in windows 10. You should manually add these registry strings.

`RegisteredOwner  (string value)` -> you can use the service account in your ESB `RegisteredOrganization (string value)`